# MySQL workbench: multiple windows

Tags: mysql-workbench

MySQL workbench is a fantastic tool. However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to create multiple windows. For example, in Sequel Pro (or TablePlus or really any other SQL client) I can have multiple windows:

[image]

Yes I know there are 'tabs' but those aren't quite the same thing. Is there a way to have multiple windows using MySQL Workbench?

---

It seems like from a few other threads this would need to be done manually via:

```
$ open -n -a MySQLWorkbench.app
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL Workbench is originally designed to be a single instance app only. On Windows this has been extended to allow multiple instances (there's a setting in the preferences) and you found a way to do this on macOS. However this bears some risks, because all instances share the same config and cache files and can write simultaneously to them, which is prone to file corruption. Also, any changes done to the configuration or connections end up in the same file, so the last change may override previously made changes in another instance.

Comment: I see. Perhaps this is a silly question, but do all of the different windows re-use the same connection? Or is that not possible and each window would have a separate connection to mysql?

Comment: No, the windows are actually different instances of the app (and hence different processes). So they always open own connections to a server, even if they use the same connection tile from the WB homescreen.